# SQL Query That Worked With .MDB Database Not Working With MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, sql

I am a novice tech person, have a ColdFusion website with .MDB (MS-Access) database that was newly converted to MySQL by my hosting service. A query that used to work perfectly for years no longer works after the conversion to MySQL, and throws error message "Every derived table must have its own alias".

As a help, here is what the query does -- and has done absolutely perfectly until now: I have a membership database. Each member has up to four email addresses, so four columns in the DB for each record, each email address associated with an email service provider domain (Comcast.net, gmail.com, aol.com, etc.).  I use the query results to list all the email domains individually with the total number of member email addresses associated with each (Comcast.net 12, gmail.com 26, aol.com 13, etc.).

What would I need to minimally modify in this query just enough to make it work with MySQL?  Thanks for your help!

```
<cfquery name="cfqGetEmailServiceProviderDomains" datasource="membership_database">
SELECT email_service_provider, COUNT(email_service_provider) AS Instances
FROM
(
    SELECT MID(email_address1, INSTR(email_address1, '@') + 1) AS email_service_provider
    FROM tblMembers
    WHERE email_address1_active = 1 
    AND email_address1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MID(email_address2, INSTR(email_address2, '@') + 1) AS email_service_provider
    FROM tblMembers
    WHERE email_address2_active = 1 
    AND email_address2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MID(email_address3, INSTR(email_address3, '@') + 1) AS email_service_provider
    FROM tblMembers
    WHERE email_address3_active = 1 
    AND email_address3 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MID(email_address4, INSTR(email_address4, '@') + 1) AS email_service_provider
    FROM tblMembers
    WHERE email_address4_active = 1 
    AND email_address4 IS NOT NULL
)
GROUP BY email_service_provider
ORDER BY email_service_provider ASC
</cfquery>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put alias on the table

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
...
) table_alias
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Does the "table_alias" refer to an actual table, or is it just a "virtual table" created temporarily so the query will work?

Comment: It's just a random name like 'a' for example.  Some dbms, like SQL Server, requires a table alias.